# Angular Module failing ngc check no idea why?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

I'm using the following module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-credit-cards in my ionic app, it works for when I build in development mode. However as soon as I add the --prod flag, I get the following error :

> Unexpected value 'NgXCreditCardsModule in 
>               /Users/Maitham/Developer/Tuto/Tuto_1.0.0/node_modules/ngx-credit-cards/build/index.js'
>   imported by the 
>               module 'AppModule in /Users/Maitham/Developer/Tuto/Tuto_1.0.0/src/app/app.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @NgModule 
>               annotation.

I really do not understand why this behaves differently in prod mode,I'm guessing its something to do with the the module being configure for angular 2 not angular 4? I could be completely wrong here. I would really appreciate someones help!

P.s. I've followed the provided instructions for installation.

Comment: Before post a question see [**Asking help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make question clear and understandable

Comment: Or probably something to do with AOT, in my case I'm trying to use this with an Ionic App, it works flawlessly in development mode, but in the compiling step it says the same thing **Please add a @NgModule annotation** .

I just don't know where to put that annotation, is it something missing on the package or just some configuration on my app, have you found the answer?

Comment: I ended up porting what I needed from ngx-credit-cards into my own methods.

Comment: Having the same issue here - I think it is a decorator missing in the package. I hope they fix this soon!